# How do I display multiple objects on one output line?

Tags: output-formatting, style

I am using `WriteString` to avoid automatic line change. But it seems like the it does not work with `Style`, like the following

```
a = 7;
Style[WriteString["stdout", a], FontSize -> 47]
```

The `FontSize` seems to be not effective. Does `WriteString` not work with `Style` at all? If so, how can I even change the font size of a `WriteString` output?

It seems like my language is not very clear, so the reason why I ask this question is, I would like to print all possible arrangement of the some letters, say I define a function

```
f[i_] := Which[i == 1, "A", i == 2, "B", i == 3, "C"]
```

and Mathematica is expected to print

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

Comment: WriteString is designed for writing to streams, such as files. In what sense are you wanting to add a style in such a situation? What file format are you dealing with? And if you AREN’T trying to write to a file, then I think you want a different function than WriteString.

Comment: As a follow up, stdout only accepts text, not styles. This is described in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic line change"?

Comment: Have you tried  `Style[a, 47]`? If not, do so. If you have, why didn't it work for you?

Comment: @m_goldberg I would like several outputs to be in the same line.

Comment: @KevinAusman I am using `WriteString` because it does not do line change automatically.

Comment: Then try paste.

Comment: @KevinAusman But I can not customize font size with `Paste`.

Comment: Paste[Style["Thing to display", 24]]

Comment: Instead of adding material to the answer below, add it to your question or submit a new answer of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there still deficiencies in my understanding of what the OP wants because of:

- language difficulties
- the OP's example does not involve "several outputs" as mentioned in comments

Despite this I will give the question a shot.

Mathematica has a number of output wrapping forms that will group multiple objects on one line. I think in your case [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) might be the form you are looking for.

Using `Row` along with `Style` allows multiple objects of almost any kind, not just strings, to be placed and formatted on one line. You can wrap `Row` in a master style and override the master style for any of the individual objects.

For example

```
p = 1; q = 2;
Style[
  Row[
    {Subscript["t", Style[p, Plain]] + Subscript[t, Style[q, Plain]], 
     Style["→", Red], "F≡I"}],
  Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 36]
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

If you must print your permutations, a more typical Mathematica style would be:

```
Do[
    Print @ Style[Row[perm], FontFamily->"Times", 46],
    {perm, Permutations[{"A", "B", "C"}]}
]
```

> During evaluation of In[434]:= ABC
>
> During evaluation of In[434]:= ACB
>
> During evaluation of In[434]:= BAC
>
> During evaluation of In[434]:= BCA
>
> During evaluation of In[434]:= CAB
>
> During evaluation of In[434]:= CBA

If you actually want to do something afterwards with the permutation, something like:

```
Table[
    Style[Row[perm], FontFamily->"Times",46],
    {perm,Permutations[{"A","B","C"}]}
]
```

> {ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA}

might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to m_goldberg's answer, I was able to figure out a solution based on his or her post

```
letter[i_] := Which[i == 1, "A", i == 2, "B", i == 3, "C"]

For[i = 1, i <= 3!, i++, 
 Print[Style[
   Row[{Style[letter[Permutations[{1, 2, 3}][[i]][[1]]], Plain], 
     Style[letter[Permutations[{1, 2, 3}][[i]][[2]]], Plain], 
     Style[letter[Permutations[{1, 2, 3}][[i]][[3]]], Plain]}], 
   FontFamily -> "Times", 46]]]
```

which will print all arrangement of letters *A*, *B* and *C*.